# How to use TTS immediately after creating View (speak failed: not bound to TTS engine)?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

in my application I need to play TTS immediately after Activity or Fragment activated. unexpectedly encountered a problem: TTS.speak is not working immediately after TTS initialization. No error or exception, only "I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine" in "Run" window.

The same code, if put TTS.speak under Button, works successfully.

Here is code:

```
package com.example.symplettsproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import java.util.Locale;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    TextToSpeech TTS;
    TextReadingUtil util;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
/
         util = new TextReadingUtil(getContext());
        util.speak("Hello World!!!");   // - not works

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                   .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.button_speak).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               util.speak("Hello World!!!");  // - it works!!!


                }
        });




    }
}
```

Here is TextReadingUtil:

```
public class TextReadingUtil {

    private TextToSpeech TTS;



    public TextReadingUtil(Context context) {

        if (TTS != null) {

            TTS.stop();
            TTS.shutdown();
        }

        TTS = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int initStatus) {
                if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    if (TTS.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()))
                            == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
                        TTS.setLanguage(new Locale(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
                    } else {
                        TTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    }
                    TTS.setPitch(1.3f);
                    TTS.setSpeechRate(0.7f);

                } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {

                }
            }
        });



    }

    public void speak (String string){

        TTS.speak(string, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);


    }



}
```

I tried to make a time delay after initiation with Thread.sleep and AsyncTask class to run TTS.speak, but whithout success. Please help, if it possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling speak when the tts has not initialized yet.

That's why it doesn't work in onCreateView() but does work on the button press (because it is initialized by the time you press the button).

The tts init is done in the background and takes time, so you can't expect it to work on the very next line after the init call.  You have to wait for your OnInitListener to be called to know when it's ready.

There is more than one way you can handle this problem ,but if you want a quick modification you can try this:

```
public class TextReadingUtil {

private TextToSpeech TTS;

// add this:
private String textToSpeakOnInit; 



public TextReadingUtil(Context context) {

    if (TTS != null) {

        TTS.stop();
        TTS.shutdown();
    }

    TTS = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int initStatus) {
            if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                if (TTS.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()))
                        == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
                    TTS.setLanguage(new Locale(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
                } else {
                    TTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                }
                TTS.setPitch(1.3f);
                TTS.setSpeechRate(0.7f);

                // tts initialized, so speak the temporary string if it has been set
                if (textToSpeakOnInit != null) {
                TTS.speak(textToSpeakOnInit, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);
                }
            } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {

            }
        }
    });



}

public void speak (String string){

    // if tts is not initialized yet, set the temporary speech string
    // that will be spoken when it is initialized.
    if (TTS == null) {
        textToSpeakOnInit = string;
    } else {
        TTS.speak(string, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);
    }

    


}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not works either. I think "if (textToSpeakOnInit != null) {..."  never works, because it's in very next line after init and nothing made to wait a time. I had succesfull solution to make static TextReadingUtil util in MainActivity and run util.speak in Fragment, but i think it is not optimal. Maybe, some solution to wait time in such situation exist...